# Is it possible to talk through websockets without using web browser?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm using node websocket `ws` module on my server and I would like to send commands to my embedded device (Arduino/GPRS module SIM808) from my server. I have used HTTP too, but it takes quite long every time my device establishes connection to send requests.

I should run the client-side written below on arduino to establish connection with webSocket `ws` sever. But on my embedded device I don't have browser and can only send `AT` commands to sockets.

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://'+location.host);

ws.onopen = function open() {
    // ws.send('something from client');
};

ws.onmessage = function incoming(data, flags) {
    console.log(data, flags);
    // flags.binary will be set if a binary data is received.
    // flags.masked will be set if the data was masked.
};

function sendMessage(input) {
    ws.send('From Client:' +input);
}
```

Is there any way I can establish socket communication through my embedded device and web server, how can I talk to web socket server without using web browser?

Comment: I'm confused about what would be the client and what would be the server.  The client will connect TO the server.  Which role does your arduino play (client or server)?  A browser can only be a client, it cannot be a server.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a webSocket is not the same thing as regular socket.  So, if you are expecting to send AT commands to your arduino over a regular socket, that is not something you can do directly with a webSocket connection.  You would need a regular TCP connection to do that.  You could, however put a webSocket server on your arduino and a browser could connect to that and the webSocket server on your arduino could then send itself the desired AT commands in response to incoming webSocket messages.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your comments, I will use arduino as client, And I've deployed my webSocket server code to Heroku, the server is working fine, but when I give my arduino board the host name and port number of my webSocket server `AT+CIPSTART="TCP",<domain name>,<port>` from Serial Monitor, it responds with `TCP CLOSED` which means nothing with that address is detected.

Comment: Does the Serial Monitor on your arduinio, specifically support webSockets?  A webSocket connection is NOT the same as a plain TCP connection.  There's a webSocket protocol and data frame format and security handshake that all must be followed in order to connect to a webSocket server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use WebSockets at Arduino.

There are many WebSocket clients:

- https://github.com/krohling/ArduinoWebsocketClient
- https://github.com/TheThingSystem/Arduino-Websocket
- https://github.com/u0078867/Arduino-Websocket-Fast